# CSS text align doesn't apply because of inherited properties

Tags: php, html, css, alignment

So I'm trying to edit inside the IPB board and add some data to the subforums.
[image: picture of forum]

As you can see the text information (status players ping harta) is aligned to the right and the fact that the "harta" variable doesn't have a fixed lenght makes it uneven, so they're not all under eachother.

I'm printing it all from php and trying to add some style to it to force it to align to the left but it won't work.

```
    if($_Query->details->tplayers==0)
    {
        $_FIScontent .= "Status: <img src=\"offline.gif\" alt=\"\"> <span style=\"color:red\"> [OFF]</span>";
        $_FIScontent .= "<br><a href=\"http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/" . $tip . ":27015/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"gametracker.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a> ";
        $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"http://" . $tip . "/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"site.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a> ";
        echo $_FIScontent;
        return $_FIScontent;
    }

    $_FIScontent .= "<div id=\"mata\" class=\"mata\" style=\"
    text-align: left;
    \"><table><tr>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>Status: <img src=\"online2.gif\" alt=\"\"> <span style=\"color:green\"> [ON]</span></td>";

    $_FIScontent .= "<td>";
    if($_Query->details->pplayers<10)
        $_FIScontent .= "Players: <span style=\"color:red\">".$_BuildStats[SERVER_PLAYERS]."</span>";
    else if($_Query->details->pplayers<20)
        $_FIScontent .= "Players: <span style=\"color:orange\">".$_BuildStats[SERVER_PLAYERS]."</span>";
    else
        $_FIScontent .= "Players: <span style=\"color:green\">".$_BuildStats[SERVER_PLAYERS]."</span>";
    $_FIScontent .= "</td>";

    //$_FIScontent .= "<tr>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>Ping: ".$_BuildStats[SERVER_LATENTA]."ms</td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>Harta: ".$_BuildStats[SERVER_MAP]."</td></table>";
    //$_FIScontent .= "</tr>";

    $_FIScontent .= "<table><td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/" . $tip . ":27015/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"gametracker.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a> ";
    $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"http://" . $tip . "/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"site.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"steam://connect/" . $tip . ":27015/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"connect.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a>";
    $_FIScontent .= "</td>";

    $_FIScontent .= "</table></div>";
    echo $_FIScontent;
    return $_FIScontent;
```

here's the link if you wanna look at it, hope that's not illegal http://furien.b-zone.ro/query/wadap.php

Edited with one table and one td for each element
[image: image of forum]

```
    $_FIScontent .= "<div id=\"mata\" class=\"mata\" style=\"
    text-align: left;
    \"><table><tr>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>Status: <img src=\"online2.gif\" alt=\"\"> <span style=\"color:green\"> [ON]</span></td>";

    $_FIScontent .= "<td>";
    if($_Query->details->pplayers<10)
        $_FIScontent .= "Players: <span style=\"color:red\">".$_BuildStats[SERVER_PLAYERS]."</span>";
    else if($_Query->details->pplayers<20)
        $_FIScontent .= "Players: <span style=\"color:orange\">".$_BuildStats[SERVER_PLAYERS]."</span>";
    else
        $_FIScontent .= "Players: <span style=\"color:green\">".$_BuildStats[SERVER_PLAYERS]."</span>";
    $_FIScontent .= "</td>";

    //$_FIScontent .= "<tr>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>Ping: ".$_BuildStats[SERVER_LATENTA]."ms</td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>Harta: ".$_BuildStats[SERVER_MAP]."</td>";
    //$_FIScontent .= "</tr>";

    $_FIScontent .= "<td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/" . $tip . ":27015/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"gametracker.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a> ";
    $_FIScontent .= "</td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"http://" . $tip . "/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"site.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a>";
    $_FIScontent .= "</td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<td>";
    $_FIScontent .= "<a href=\"steam://connect/" . $tip . ":27015/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"connect.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"25\" width=\"75\"></a>";
    $_FIScontent .= "</td>";

    $_FIScontent .= "</tr></table></div>";
    echo $_FIScontent;
    return $_FIScontent;
```

Comment: I can't find what is wrong in your code, you don't have <tr></tr> elements to make them display one after another.

Comment: A few things I dont understand along with missing tr closing tag is why you use a new table for the topics and replies? But more on topic is that each row in your table show be wrapped in its own tr

Comment: I've searched far and wide. For some reason, somehow, the css of the forum template forces them to display like they do. I can't seem to get rid of any properties set to the table by the forum (can't reduce padding or anything) \n The tr tags are missing because I have 4 elements on the top and 3 elements on the bottom. Also the forum displays them the same way anyways, with the padding on the left, so table columns are pushed away depending on the size of the data.

Comment: add this little css rule to your stylesheet and see what it does: `td { text-align: left !important; }`

Comment: Lol its impossible to use the developer tools in chrome on your site because your DOM is being changed in the table. Maybe its that status image.

Comment: yeah @Mic1780 I know. I'm trying that !important thing and then if it's not working gonna remove the auto refresh and put it on onload

Comment: Well the reason I recommended the !important is because if it does not change the alignment of the text then it is already being aligned left. !important takes priority over the more specific CSS rules that would overwrite the td rule.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to stop the server calls from your setInterval and looked at the DOM. it shows that your status player ping and harta are already text aligned left. Its acting the way it is because it does not have a consistent table structure to follow. This means that because each table structure is different per row of information, the layout will be different.

The solution to this is to use a single table to house the information. Each column of information needs its own td. For information like topics and replies you can just make a new table inside a td for that column.

Comment: edited OP with proper edits, the data is still pushed to the left

Comment: @AronH. Each of your "status" sections is its own table. Unless you assign specific widths to each cell within each of those tables, or make them part of the parent table, they will adjust separately to the data contained within.

Comment: @RyanKinal is correct. If no width is set on a td then widths are inferred and will vary. When the information is all in the parent table the inferred width wont matter to the text formatting. Everything will be aligned correctly per column and all column widths would be the same.

Comment: can I somehow do that from within the php? or do I need to fiddle around in the css file. I would like to add a minimum width to the map column only if possible

Comment: If you mean the td widths you can fiddle with it in css. If you are trying to make a parent table for all info you need to change your html.

Comment: well yeah I'm using php to insert html in the page, that's what I meant